# Проблема с exe файлом, полученным через pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-3.7

после компиляции программы в exe-файл через pyinstaller,
программа перестает правильно работать

Что делает программа:

1. -Берутся координаты для мыши и задержки из файла(XYZ.txt).
2. -Выполняются клики через pyautogui.click
3. -Выполняются клики через pyautogui.click
4. -Создается скриншот и сохраняется в папке программы
5. -Выполняется вход в почту(тоже через текстовый файл login.txt)
6. -Создается сообщение, к которому прикрепляется скриншот(screen.png)
7. -Идет рассылка скриншотов на email-пользователей(Забиты в файле emails.txt) с почты(Забита в файл sender.txt)

И все это в цикле + внутри цикла конструкция Try/Except(в try сам код программы^^^, а в except вывод ошибки + ожидание).

В py-файле все работает, но в exe-файле происходит зацикливание кликов(Постоянно выполняется только 1ый и 2ой пункт)

В чем может быть проблема?
Буду очень благодарен помощи.
Заранее спасибо!

```
from os import system
import os
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication


while True:
    try:
        z = []
        x = []
        y = []
        p = []
        l = []
        s = []
        with open('XYZ.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                z.append(line.replace('\n', ''))
            print(z)

        for i in range(0, len(z)):
            c = z[i]
            c = c.split(' ')
            x.append(int(c[0]))
            y.append(int(c[1]))
            p.append(int(c[2]))

        for i in range(0, len(x)):
            pyautogui.click(x[i], y[i], duration=p[i])

        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        img.save('screen.png')
        sleep(5)
        print('Начало отправки')
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        print('Создан объект msg')
        msg['Subject'] = 'График'
        print('Создана тема письма')
        f = open('sender.txt', 'r')
        for line in f:
            s.append(line)
            send = s[0]
        print(send)
        f.close()
        msg['From'] = send
        print('Определен адресс отправителя')

        part = MIMEText('...\n')
        msg.attach(part)
        print('В сообщение был добавлен текст')

        part = MIMEApplication(open('screen.png', 'rb').read())
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                        'attachment', filename='screen.png')
        msg.attach(part)
        print('В сообщение был добавлен файл')

        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.yandex.ru')
        print('Обращение к серверу')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        f = open('login.txt', 'r')
        for line in f:
            l.append(line)
            log = l[0]
            log = log.split(' ')
            log[1] = log[1].replace('\n', '')
        print(log)
        f.close()
        server.login(log[0], log[1])
        print('Вход в почту')
        f = open('emails.txt', 'r')
        print('Считывание emails')
        for line in f:
            print('Отправлено на {}'.format(line.replace('\n', '')))
            server.sendmail(
                msg['From'], [line.replace('\n', '')], msg.as_string())
            sleep(5)
        f.close()
        sleep(86350)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        sleep(60)
```

Comment: А исключение какое нибудь возникает?

Comment: http://www.py2exe.org/ Вот если не поможет ищи в гугле их там много тестируй, проверяй

Comment: Возможно следует использовать абсолютные пути.

Comment: Никаких исключений не возникает, программа просто делает вывод координат на экран, делает клики и зацикливается